# When should I update a database to reflect property changes?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, mvvm

I am new to WPF and I am building a small app with Linq To Entities (and SQLite database).

I just would like to know, where do I have to call my methods in order to update the database, when a property has changed ?
I would say in the property in ViewModel like this :

```
public string FirstName
{
    get
    {
        return this.person.FirstName;
    }
    set
    {
        this.person.FirstName = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("FirstName");
        this.person.updateFirstname(value);
    }
}
```

I am not sure if this is the best solution...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem of when to save to the database gives rise to the [Unit of Work pattern](http://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html). Linq-to-Entities has a reasonable implementation of this with the [ObjectContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.aspx), where data is queued up in the context and then saved to the database when the logical unit of work is complete.

In your example, you are already setting the property on the L2E entity, Person, which is likely connected to the context. When you call [ObjectContext.SaveChanges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336792.aspx), this will be saved without the need for the `updateFirstname` method.

The thing you have to decide is when to call `ObjectContext.SaveChanges` (and thus end the unit of work), and doing this when the user explicitly saves or when the form is closed (optionally propmting for the user to commit or discard changes) is a reasonable approach here. To implement this, your viewmodels reference the ObjectContext and can call the `SaveChanges` method when the user action (usually modeled with a WPF `ICommand` [published by the viewmodel and bound to the view](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405484%28v=PandP.40%29.aspx#sec11)) is executed.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of the ObjectContext, I will look into this

Comment: If you are getting `Person` from Linq-to-Entities, how else are you querying if not using the `ObjectContext`?

Comment: Hum sorry, in fact I am using it, but I didn't know it was called ObjectContext...

Comment: Well, good, then you're most of the way there. You want to probably call `SaveChanges` on it to persist the changes you've made to the `Person` entity.

Comment: So in this scenario, `ObjectContext.SaveChanges` will be called from his VM and therefore the VM will be tightly coupled to his DAL containing his EF model? Or maybe forget about the DAL and just create the EF model in the main project? Don't see how this could be a good idea regardless of the project size...

Comment: Is it better to call it in the ViewModel ?

Comment: On a small project this dependency is really not a problem. Introducing an abstraction to allow you to vary the two layers independently is difficult to maintain with little benefit.

Comment: @Peekyou - yes, but not on every change. Usually when the form is closing or the user clicks "Save". If you have an `ICommand` which you bind to a button on the WPF view, you then handle the execution of this command in the viewmodel, and call `ObjectContext.SaveChanges`. In my answer I linked here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405484%28v=PandP.40%29.aspx#sec11 to show you how to do this.

Comment: The clear benefit is learning how to create a persistance layer and use it within an MVVM app the right way for an enterprise level app from the get go, instead of learning how to create a tightly coupled, monolithic app that will not scale...

Comment: "right way for an enterprise level app" - this is not really engineering, it's just mimicking what others do. How do you know that this is an enterprise app? Not all apps have the same requirements, and picking the right patterns to go with the level of the problem is what is needed, not blind application of enterprise-level designs.

Answer (score 0):

You should concentrate your updates around unit-of-work rather than around individual fields. If your database is properly normalized each row will represent an entity and should be treated as such, updates to an entity should keep an entity in "valid" state. In your scenario if you update person's first name with intention of also updating last name if the app or server blows up your person record will be invalid.

In terms of MVVM, I usually either piggyback on grid's "update entire row at once" strategy and route that event into viewmodel or I just give them a save button :)

Answer (score 0):

It is best to inject a service Interface into your ViewModel constructor and use some type of service to update the database. 
This way you end up with loosely coupled system and your ViewModel stays agnostic of your Data Access Layer as it should...

Comment: He's not using a service to get injected, he's specifically using Entity Framework.

Comment: Is this reasonable with a very small application ?

Comment: @Peekyou - it is reasonable, but probably not needed, since you are explicitly using Entity Framework. This is a sort of generic non-answer which won't help you much, I'm afraid.

Comment: @codekaizen And what is there to stop you from using EF from within a service?